# Background processing in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, cron, scheduled-tasks, message-queue

We are investigating how we can move away from the traditional cronjob to a distributed task queue. This so we can have:

- Stateless workers which can be autoscaled
- Proper logging
- The possibility to restart tasks
- Prioritisation
- Scheduling/ queueing
- An interface for non tech personel

We have experience with [Amazon SWF](https://aws.amazon.com/swf/). It's a great tool but very much amazon. Not user friendly at all, when you compare the interface with for example [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/). Also it's not build to schedule events for the next 6 months which is a requirement.

Other queueing tools I have looked at are:

- [celeryproject.org](http://www.celeryproject.org/)
- [iron.io](http://www.iron.io/)
- [rabbitmq.com](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

My question is what the best background queue, worker and dashboard currently is which **can be used by a php** stack.

Answer (score 0):

What you are writing here doesn't sound like the usecase for an online queue service, but for like one for a self hosted queue. The best known might be [**beanstalkd**](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) which is a queue service running on your own server, so you are very free to schedule and queue for whatever timeframe you want. Personally, I like [**redis**](http://redis.io), which does a good job here, too.

Also, have a look at [laravel](http://laravel.com). It will provide you with an out of the box working queueing and scheduling system with connectors for both mentionend self hosted queueing providers, but also with iron, amazon sqs,... and is easily extendable.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I took a look at [laravel queueing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#introduction), [symfony bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/jms/job-queue-bundle) , [another symfony bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/uecode/qpush-bundle). But they still lack the UI of sidekiq which I love. Any though about that?

Comment: Who not Code it. @Kim

Comment: good point :). It's always about ROI right, but if there is no other way then sure, we'll code it.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @michael said, there's also [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

Also, Amazon has [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) that can be used alongside with [SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) to form a job Queue.

There's not a "best" one, but I believe [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) is the easiest one to set up

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in Laravel queues, they have a beautiful UI called [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/horizon)